# Typescript top level await with path aliases

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths, developer-mode

I want to use top level await, but at the same time not lose the ability to use path aliases, both in assembly and in developer mode.

I tried to use ts-node-dev with tsconfig-paths, but got the error: "Must use import to load ES Module"

Comment: Are you compileng to cjs or esnext?

Comment: Is your package `"type": "module"`?

Comment: @Dimava

Is your package "type": "module"? - Yes.
Are you compileng to cjs or esnext? - ESNext.